# Factory method for each hierarchy

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I'm working on an application with many inheritance hierarchies that are not directly related.

Do I have to assign a factory method for each hierarchy in the client code to select a certain class from each hierarchy to instantiate upon the user selection through the GUI?

Answer (score 2):

Instead if a concret Factory you may take a look at the Abstract Factory

> Abstract Factory offers the interface for creating a family of related objects, without explicitly specifying their classes.

[Reference](http://www.oodesign.com/abstract-factory-pattern.html)

If objects are not related, I think you can't avoid having a factory for each object. Take a look at the Dependency Injection architecture , it could be an interesting option [Dependency Injection vs Factory Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557742/dependency-injection-vs-factory-pattern)

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the point is the required classes aren't family, they are not related, so abstract factory isn't valid here

Comment: What do you mean when you say "inheritance hierarchies that are not directly related?"

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this webpage, which demonstrates using the Abstract Factory pattern with multiple inheritance hierarchies: http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternAbstract.aspx.