# injecting providers into dynamically created objects in NestJs

Tags: dependency-injection, nestjs

I have this working example of injecting providers into my object, but I would like to know if there is a better way to solve this, than to use the Factory class below. Or do you avoid situations like this somehow completely? Is this even in-line with how dependency-injection is supposed to work?

See this gist https://gist.github.com/sezanzeb/4cca6f0e7689d75b5a1ec546c471c430 for the code sample.

I have searched a lot through StackOverflow and the NestJs examples, but couldn't find relevant answers. Only something similar in Angular.

Answer (score 0):

There are no NestJs (Or Angular) specific guidelines or best practices for this, as far as I can tell. This question needs to be answered by looking at the idea of dependency injection as a pattern.

Dependency Injection seems to be more about separating the instatiation of objects from where they are needed.

- Either via constructor injection (https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Dependency-Injection-By-Hand)
- Or via property injection with methods like `setFoo`
- Also see [What is dependency injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130794/what-is-dependency-injection?rq=1)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection

> A basic benefit of dependency injection is decreased coupling between classes and their dependencies.
>
> By removing a client's knowledge of how its dependencies are implemented, programs become more reusable, testable and maintainable.
>
> This also results in increased flexibility: a client may act on anything that supports the intrinsic interface the client expects.

Using a factory, like proposed in the gist in the original question, fulfills all those criteria. There is, as far as I can tell, no built in way for NestJs to do such a thing, but it is easy to just create your own factory and inject that into your service.

Factories and DI are related: [Dependency Injection vs Factory Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557742/dependency-injection-vs-factory-pattern?rq=1)

> "The DI pattern does not require any frameworks. You can do DI by manually writing factories which do DI. DI frameworks just make it easier"
>
> "Factory pattern can be called as a tool to implement DI."
>
> "Instead of instantiating the parts itself a car asks for the parts it needs to function."
>
> ```js
> static class CarFactory
> {
>     public ICar BuildCar()
>     {
>         Engine engine = new Engine();
>         SteeringWheel steeringWheel = new SteeringWheel();
>         Tires tires = new Tires();
>         ICar car = new RaceCar(engine, steeringWheel, tires);
>         return car;
>     }
> }
> ```

So to conclude, yes, I would consider the proposal in the gist as best practice for this matter:

```js
@Injectable()
class HeroFactory {
    constructor(private readonly environmentService: EnvironmentService) { }

    public createWizard(name: string): Wizard {
        return new Wizard(name, 1, this.environmentService);
    }
}
```